# Detect if user speaks using the Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO permission

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, speech-recognition

I have a use case like if user speaks I must show some wave icon and on user stops speaking the wave icon must disappear , How can I detect if the user is speaking ? Kindly help me on it

```
override fun onResume() {
        checkValue(recorder.maxAmplitude);
    }
    fun checkValue(amplitude: Int) {
        var amplitude = amplitude
        try {
            if (amplitude > 1000) {
                amplitude = recorder.getMaxAmplitude()
                Thread.sleep(2000)
                isUserSpeaking.value = true
                Toast.makeText(this,"User Speaking", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } else if (isUserSpeaking.value) {
                Toast.makeText(this,"User Speaking else if", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder) for recording audio you can periodically request amplitude with [MediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder#getMaxAmplitude()).

```
fun checkValue(amplitude: Int) {
    var amplitude = amplitude
    try {
        if (amplitude > 1000) {
            amplitude = recorder.getMaxAmplitude()
            Thread.sleep(2000)
            isUserSpeak = true
        } else if (isUserSpeak) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Stop")
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

and use this function like

```
 checkValue(recorder.getMaxAmplitude());
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.... I have added the code and made the checkValue call in the oncreate, function triggered at the launch as amplitude is 0 nothing happens . Even on audio I don't see the function gets called .... Any suggestions

Comment: @arun can u add your code ?

Comment: Edited the Question, in that you can see the code I have added from your comment @Pratik